# HTML DIV element Disappears with no content

Tags: css, layout, html

When I create an HTML div element with no content, it disappears.

When the div is populated, like this HTML, then it works right.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style>
    .nav {
        width: 26%;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-right: 2%;
        background-color: #FF0000;
    }
    .content {
        width: 56%;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-right: 2%;
        background-color: #0000FF;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 600px;">
        <div class="nav"><p>nav</p></div>
        <div class="content"><p>content</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following (expected) output:

[image]

However, if I change the `div` element with the `class = nav` to no content:

```
<div class="nav"></div>
```

The red box disappears:

[image]

It's like there is no div there!  How can I always have the program show the div with no content?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the div is empty the element has no height.  So what's actually happening is that it's there but has 0 height.

You could put something in it (like `&nbsp;` or give it `height` and/or `line-height`. I'd suggest giving the other div the same height.

Comment: Thanks, CSS can be a PITA (every|some)times. I went with the `&nbsp;` approach.

Answer (score 4):

Put a non-breaking space in it. That's what I do when I need *something*, but not nothing. You may also be able to give it an explicit height to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the  contains some kind of content.   is usually the best. It ensures that there is at least something for the browser to display/render. This also might be a cause of your DTD.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that call cause this is improperly nested tags or tags that are not closed.

Make sure all tags are properly nested and closed.

Answer (score 1):

This approach lets the div be empty, by using inline-block display.  You force the height.

CSS:

```
.nav { 
    width: 26%; 
    height: 2em;
    display: inline-block; 
    float: left; 
    background-color: #FF0000; 
} 
.content { 
    width: 56%;
    height:2em;    
    display: inline-block;    
    background-color: #0000FF; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 600px;"> 
    <div class="nav"></div> 
    <div class="content"><p>content</p></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alix,

you need to add a height value to the class .nav

```
    <!doctype html> 
<head> 
<style> 
    .nav { 
        width: 26%; 
        height: 50px;
        display: inline; 
        float: left; 
        margin-left: 2%; 
        margin-right: 2%; 
        background-color: #FF0000; 
    } 
    .content { 
        width: 56%; 
        display: inline; 
        float: left; 
        margin-left: 2%; 
        margin-right: 2%; 
        background-color: #0000FF; 
    } 
</style> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <div style="width: 600px;"> 
        <div class="nav"></div> 
        <div class="content"><p>content</p></div> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

after you add a height value also add a display property to the nav class like:

```
height:1em;
display:block;
```